# Not able to disable System.Diagnostics.Trace in NUnit

Tags: .net, nunit, trace, system.diagnostics

In our production application we have a custom Trace Listener, but this is not present when testing specific units of the application. So I want to easily disable tracing. If I don't I will get an error from the default trace listener saying the format string is incorrect.

I can do this by coding (and this works):

```
[Setup]
public void Setup()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear();
}
```

But it is tedious to find all the [Setup] and add the line of code. Instead, I want to modify the config file.

So, for my test (test.dll) I have a config file test.dll.config. And it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <clear/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="StartingMonthColumn" value="7"/>
    <add key="CategoryHeadingColumn" value="1"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But this does not work. I know the config is loaded because I can read the value for StartingMonthColumn.

But the system.diagnostics section seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The test.dll.config file is used by NUnit for a very few things. It doesn't do anything with tracing. You might have some luck if you modified NUnit's own config file, which is what .NET is looking at. As a test, modify the config for the console runner. Use command-line options to specify that the tests should be run in the same process - /process:Single will work in both NUnit 2.6.4 and 3.0+. If this works, you will also have to modify the config for both NUnit agents for when you are running out of process.

An alternative code-based approach is to craeate a top-level SetUpFixture for each assembly and put the disabling code there in the SetUp (2.6.4) or OneTimeSetUp (3.x) method.

Comment: I have added the system.diagnostics section to each of nunit.exe.config, nunit-agent.exe.config, nunit-agent-x86.exe.config, nunit-console.exe.config, nunit-console-x86.exe.config and nunit-x86.exe.config all without any luck. As I mentioned above, I don't want to disable using code.

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using?

Comment: 2.5.10. Thinking I should try the latest 3.2, I downloaded it only to find no GUI. Found GUI in GitHub. Downloaded and compiled it. Tried to run my test dll, but got message "No suitable tests found in xxx" so I guess there is stuff I need to do to migrate to 3.2. And time I do not have right now.

Comment: OK. We have a work-around. We created a class with a static constructor that clears all existing Trace Listeners. It then checks for a configuration setting and adds our Listener only if the configuration item is present. Since it is not in the unit test configuration files, there are no Trace Listeners during unit testing and all is well.

Comment: 2.5.10 is pretty old for sure. You might try 2.6.4, the latest and last V2 release. In 2.5.10, we add a listener of our own, making sure to leave all yours in place. That far back, we might even have something in the nunit config that controls this - I don't have a copy handy to check.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!